# Does the order of applying rules in Sequent Calculus matter?

Tags: first-order-logic, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

Suppose we want to prove some $\Gamma \models \Delta$ in (first-order logic) sequent calculus LK.
We start with the sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$, and arbitrarily apply rules backward until we reach sequents that only contain atomic formulae. Then, either the sequents are axioms (e.g. $A \vdash A$), or not (e.g. $A \vdash B$).

Now, suppose that $\Gamma \models \Delta$. If we apply rules arbitrarily, are we guaranteed to always end up with axioms ($A \vdash A$)? Or can the order of application of rules change that outcome?

Another way of asking this: If at some point in the derivation we see a sequent with only atoms that is not an axiom (e.g. $A \vdash B$), can we immediately infer that $\Gamma \not\models \Delta$?

Is the outcome different if $\Gamma \models \Delta$ would only contain propositions, no predicates?

Thanks for the help :)

PS: Maybe this was a little unclear... Both $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ can be one or more well-formed formulae.

Comment: Basically, the order is deterministic. Rules act on a single connective or quantifier at the time and we can apply a rule only to the principal connective. I.e. The formula $p \to (q \land r)$ can be decomposed only with the rule for $\to$.

Comment: I would disagree. You most of the time have at least two choices: Apply a rule on the left side of the sequent, or on the right. Also, there might be different rules that apply.For example, the exchange / weakening rules apply in most cases.